# Creating a loop to filter data and create a summary

Tags: r

I want to create a loop which can filter data according to c("published" ,"pending","not designed") and then calculate the percentage distribution between text of Name column and create a list of summaries.

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("ABC","DCA","GOL",NA,"MNA",NA,"VAN","KDA","JHA","MNA","LKO","HUN","GOL","DCA","JHA"),
                 Goal =c("published","pending","not designed","published","not designed","not designed","pending","pending","published","pending","not designed","pending","pending","pending","not designed"),
                 Target_1 = c(3734,2639,2604,NA,2793,2688,2403,7612,8653,8653,8765,3645,5976,4362,7593),
                 Target_2 = c(3322,2016,2310,NA,3236,3898,2309,5632,7846,5863,5936,4067,6876,6876,5582),
                 Target_3 = c(3785,2585,3750,NA,2781,3589,2830,6785,8636,7548,9065,7954,8576,9989,4892))
```

first loop to filter data according var in Goal, then calculate percentage distribution for frequency of variables in required column so here column will be Name

input var should be dataset and percentage column

list of summaries should be like, this is sample output not actual.
the output should be like list of summaries like below

[image]

Comment: Are you certain your expected output is achievable with your example? It's difficult to see how 'n' and 'percent' are calculated.

Comment: actually this is the required output

Comment: Please explain how to mathematically transform the sample data to arrive at the expected output.

Comment: For example your input, row 9 has `name = JHA` and `Goal = published`. It has target values `8653, 7846, 8636`. How do those three numbers become your result, `n = 22` and `percent = 44%`?

Comment: That is sample output , not calculated on actual data

Comment: @str_rst Just to clarify, is this your goal?  To roll up `df` into a list of three `data.frame`s (for `"pending"`, `"published"`, and `"not designed"`) , where each `data.frame` summarizes its subset of data by listing each `Name`, the count of that `Name` in the subset, and the frequency (as a percentage) at which that name appears (ie. the `Name`s count divided by the total number of observations in the subset)?

Comment: @Greg yes right , but To roll up df into a list of three data.frames (for "pending", "published", and "not designed")   , with the help of loop

Comment: @str_rst Just to be clear, is it absolutely _required_ that you use a _loop_, per se?  I can envision plenty of elegant solutions that will work on reasonably large data and involve no cumbersome loops...

Comment: @Greg so the require of loop is also because , i can update more required thing in that . so for now loop is the only requirement.

Comment: @str_rst Virtually any (useful) transformations you can do with a loop can also be done via packages like `dplyr`.  Are there other operations you want to do alongside this summarization; operations that involve something other than transforming, calculating, or summarizing the dataset?  If so, please describe them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output you want is a `list()` of `data.frame`s with totals rows, and you're fine letting R handle the looping "under the hood", then here's a function (per [your request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67888773/creating-a-loop-to-filter-data-and-create-a-summary/67889268#comment119996498_67889268)) that will summarize a given dataset (of the structure seen in your `df`) into a list of `data.table`s (also `tabyls` with totals rows) named and filtered by `Goal`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)
library(janitor)


# ...
# Code to generate your dataset.
# ...


# By Goal, summarize the dataset into a named list of tabyls, filtered however
# you wish, each with a totals row.
my_summarizer <- function(# The data.frame to summarize.
                          my_df,
                          # A vector of Goals; the others are filtered out.
                          goals = NULL,
                          # Omit missing values from calculations?
                          na.rm = TRUE,
                          # Value to fill the totals cell for a non-numeric field.
                          totals_fill = NA,
                          # Title of the totals row.
                          totals_title = "",
                          # Further arguments to format percentage and totals row.
                          ...) {
  # Select all if goals is not given; otherwise select specified Goals.
  if(!is.null(goals)) {
    my_df <- my_df %>% filter(Goal %in% as.character(goals))
  }
  
  return(sapply(X = my_df %>%
                    
  ##############################################################################
  ##################  If you want to do further operations, START HERE.  #######
  ##############################################################################

                    # Tally the counts.
                    group_by(Goal) %>% count(Name) %>%
                    # Calculate the percentages.
                    mutate(percent = n/sum(n, na.rm = na.rm)) %>% ungroup() %>%
                    # Format the percentages.
                    mutate(percent = formattable::percent(x = percent, ...)) %>%

  ##############################################################################
  ##################  Further operations END HERE.  ############################
  ##############################################################################

                    # Split into (and name) list of tables by Goal.
                    split(f = as.factor(.$Goal)),
  
                # Hide Goal field and add totals row; result is a data.table
                # also of class tabyl, to store structural info about totals.
                FUN = function(x){return(x %>%
                                           # Hide Goal field.
                                           select(-one_of("Goal")) %>%
                                           # Add totals row to each table.
                                           janitor::adorn_totals(where = "row",
                                                                 fill = totals_fill,
                                                                 na.rm = na.rm,
                                                                 name = totals_title)
                                         )},
                # Keep as a list.
                simplify = FALSE,
                # Keep the names.
                USE.NAMES = TRUE))
}
```

As you can see, I have left room for you to add further operations to the summarization process, if you so desire.  Now, this function can be applied to your `df` as follows:

```
# Summarize dataset, filtered to only the Goals you want; format percentages
# without decimals.
my_summary <- my_summarizer(df, goals = c("published", "pending"), totals_title = "TOTAL", digits = 0)


# View results.
my_summary
```

The results should look like this:

```
$pending
  Name n percent
   DCA 2     29%
   GOL 1     14%
   HUN 1     14%
   KDA 1     14%
   MNA 1     14%
   VAN 1     14%
 TOTAL 7    100%

$published
  Name n percent
   ABC 1     33%
   JHA 1     33%
  <NA> 1     33%
 TOTAL 3    100%
```

Unless some **third party** (like a teacher) has demanded you implement this summarization via a manually generated loop, I strongly recommend *against* such a loop, as its performance is generally inferior to transformations via `dplyr` (or `data.table`s), which can elegantly implement virtually every aggregation and summarization trick in the book.

## Note

See the other [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67889268) by [Ian Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13095326) (and also the `gt` package), if your output is expected as **not** (1) an actual `list()` (of `data.table`s) that matches the picture you supplied, **but rather** (2) a pictorial visualization (as a `gt` object) displayed in the style of that picture.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `gt`. It's a little bit hacky because as far as I can tell there is no way to supply multiple formatters to a summary row:

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)
df %>%
  group_by(Goal) %>%
  count(Name) %>% 
  mutate(percent = n/sum(n)) %>%
  gt() %>%
  summary_rows(groups = TRUE, columns = c(n,percent),
               fns = list(` ` = ~ ifelse(sum(.,na.rm = TRUE) == 1, "100%", sum(.,na.rm = TRUE))),
               formatter = fmt_passthrough) %>%
  fmt_percent(rows = TRUE, columns = percent, decimals = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: actually loop is required to filter dataset against , because actual data loop will work fast and this will take too much time as the data is very big

Comment: I disagree that a loop will be faster than `dplyr::group_by()`. Please provide reproducible data to back up that assertion.

Comment: actually i want to automate it like function where i can provide var for (Published, not designed, pending) . so suppose if i want this summary only for published and pending ) so that loop can apply for those two only and i can get desired column summary like above. hope i am able to explain now

Comment: i want to create  a loop that will instead of filtering only c("published" ,"pending","not designed") data and will also perform 
Calculate percentage distribution between entries  in Name

Comment: Both of these are easily achieved, for example with `filter(Goal %in% c("Published","not designed","pending"))` or `group_by(Goal,Name) %>% count(OtherVariable)`. Unfortunately, we can only help you with problems you fully explain to us.